# how do I get some objects from an array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For Example: I have an array of object which consists 100 object in the array. and I want to show first 6 object in my react component. how do I loop that so it shows only those?

Comment: You should add a sample of your array, and your React code, to the question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` to grab a range of elements and then `map` over it for your react component.

eg.

```
return 
<div>
  {elements.slice(0, 6).map((value) => <div>{value}</div>)}
</div>
```